# AWS EC2 Instance + CloudFront: CloudFront domain resolves to misdirected URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have greatly benefited from this forum before and even with this current issue I have exhausted all my knowledge, research leads, and quite a few hours before I decided to put in the question.

So I have an EC2 Instance mapped at

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
```

It's an EC2 Linux system and domain hosted in the AWS Route 53 service.

Actual PHP application is in folder `www\html\FolderA`.

I have resolved this by using the `DocumentRoot` directive in APACHE and SSL conf and it works.

I have two separate independent host configs. One for port 80 and the other for 443.

Host:80, port 80 is being redirected to 443 and DocumentRoot mapped.

Host:443, only DocumentRoot mapped, NO redirection.

When mydomain.com( or www subdomain) is accessed, target index.php runs application works without showing `FolderA` in the URL which is intended. It all works.

Now in my CloudFront distribution, I  configured origin connection via the only https/443 and have used public EC2 domain name as the origin. I have chosen to route all in-coming viewer traffic port 80 to 443.

Summary of Setup

`Viewer => 80/443 =>Redirect=> 443 => CloudFront Distribution`

`CloudFront Distribution -> 443 -> Origin`

Now when I take my CloudFront domain name and try to access it via https/HTTP in the browser

Output of Setup

Expected: `https://xxxCloudFrontDomainname.net`  =>   `https://mydmain.com/`

Actual: `https://xxxCloudFrontDomainname.net`  =>   `https://mydmain.com/FolderA`

I have checked my conf files both HTTPD and SSL( and any other conf files I could find in the system folder for apache)  and Htaccess 10 times or more to verify.  There are no such redirections apart from one in `HOST:80`, but that shouldn't matter as I am using HTTPS to access the CloudFront domain. In any case, the result is always the same as above.

When using https as origin connection preference there shouldn't ideally be any redirection at all.

Besides, I don't have any such active redirection which could have that effect, `https://mydmain.com/FolderA`.

I am failing to understand why the "FolderA" is appended onto the original Host path when using CloudFront domain name as test.

I did change DNS configuration already but removed it after the setup didn't work. Before DNS config works, My understanding is when I type in my CloudFront domain name in the address bar and hit Enter I should be directed to the original Host website "mydomain.com".

Moreover, SSL certs for the CloudFront domain are obtained from AWS, and for the original domain are obtained from Lets Encrypt, and that part of equations works though worth mentioning.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `CFD`? Is it your CloudFront Domain?

Comment: Sorry yes, CFD => CloudFront Distribution and, CFD Domain is the endpoint for distribution.